# Javascript glitch breaking a POST function for select input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

thanks for taking a moment to look at my question.

I have a requirement to create a data collection method that is done in three phases. Final data is to be stored in a MySQL database.
1st - Personal details (this part is easy and has been completed)
2nd - Expense details (this part is the part that is my headache)
3rd - Receipt scan upload (this part is also relatively easy and has been completed also).

Technologies in use - html, php5, javascript, mysql, running on a standard LAMP stack.
Personal limitation - me. Not very fluent in php and have not used it in a few years.

1st screen works perfectly.
3rd screen works perfectly but requires completion to email the user upon finalisation of completing the process. Not a problem as I have done this before.

2nd screen has two tables, each with a small variety of input fields. The first of these tables is using JavaScript to clone table rows so that the user can propagate as many of these rows as they need. Each row is comprised of the following fields:

```
<input class="mus3" type="text" name="reg_travel_date1" id="reg_travel_date1" maxlength="20"><br><input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="+1 row" class="button" style="width: 80px; margin-top: 18px;">
<textarea class="mus1" name="reg_travel_from1" id="reg_travel_from1" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
<textarea class="mus2" name="reg_travel_to1" id="reg_travel_to1" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
<input class="mus4" type="text" name="reg_kms_travelled1" id="reg_kms_travelled1" maxlength="10" onkeydown="validateNumber(event);">
    <select class="select" style="width: 120px;" name="exp_type_car_travel1">
     <option selected>Type...</option>
     <option value="Seminar">Seminar</option>
     <option value="Rural Travel">Rural Travel</option>
     <option value="Conference">Conference</option>
     <option value="Exam">Exam</option>
     <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
<input type="text" name="reg_claimable_kms1" id="reg_claimable_kms1" maxlength="10" class="mus5" onkeydown="validateNumber(event);">
```

To see further detail, I have posted ALL of the code used at the following links (there is not enough space in here).

I have had to double up on my linked code as I am only permitted to post two links, it appears.

index.php FOLLOWED BY C.claim2.php : http://pastebin.com/wufh4Q47
css_file.css FOLLOWED BY C.claim.php (complete and working) : http://pastebin.com/iGnEsTC3

The jquery.min.js file is version jQuery v2.0.3

I've pasted the code for the first screen which is working fine, as an indication of the hoped for behaviour of the second screen.

**PROBLEM:**
I am trying to make it so that the select field in the JS clone function will increment it's name/id like the text and textbox fields do (or did before this particular version, for some reason). It has always cloned itself with the exact same name as the starting row which has caused serious problems in the resulting post function.

Also, for some reason that may or may not be related, the select field always posts a blank value, regardless of how many cloned rows there are. I do not know why, nor how to fix this.

Can anyone help? I am not skilled in JS at all, the JS used on this project was written for me by a friend who is also wondering why it's not quite working as desired.

Thank you. :)

Comment: is only your select field with a name given above `exp_type_car_travel1` you suspected makes the error or all your select fields? Try to echo or alert or use console.log first the value of those fields so that you can check if you're on the right track...

Comment: Hello Nesmar. The other three select fields that are based within the second table are functioning perfectly. None of these are part of the JS cloning situation and so it stands to reason that only the select field in the first table (of which the code is supplied above) is affected **because** of the JS cloning process. All other fields within the row increment by name during the JS cloning process by one, and infact since posting my original query, now the select field also does this, but values sent as part of the POST process are still vacant during the POST transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, ignore this question now - the situation has been resolved fully and is working perfectly. It appears there is a bug in JQuery that has been chosen as to be "not to be fixed" as the overheads to do so are too high. This problem results in the  choices to be blank, their 'name="something"' values being dropped. We have a work around now and the function now performs perfectly, thanks to my friend. Much appreciation Crystal!